# How can I sum value of distinct columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two column(col1 and col 2) `col1` is VARCHAR datatype and `col2` is INT. I have many records with duplicate `col1` value. Now I need to sum(col2) where `col1` is distinct. How can i do this ?

I tried like this before, but didn't work.

```
Select distinct 
    col1, sum(col2) as col2 
from mytable 
group by col1

Select sum(col2) 
from
    (Select distinct col1 from mytable)
```

Comment: To better answer your question. I think it would make sense for you to declare both entities of varchar datatype unless you have a constraint that is really imposed on you. I don't seem to be understanding what you are trying to achieve here. (I believe you are trying to do an join of some kind). Please try and be a little more specific.

Comment: Show some data and results,  and explain how it differs from what you expect.  Without at least that we cannot really help.

Comment: hm.., it's unclear what you need, but looks like you don't need to use distint, just group by: `select col1, sum(col2) from mytable group by col1`

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        col1
        ,col2
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) AS rn
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT
    SUM(col2) AS SumCol2
FROM CTE
WHERE rn=1
;
```

You should decide which row you want to pick if there are several rows with the same value in `col1`. The query above will pick the row with the smallest `col2`.